# Thunderbird keeps caching web image in signature

Tags: thunderbird, email-signature

I have an HTML signature with a web-based image.  The image changes about once a month, but Thunderbird keeps using an old image.  I believe it's being cached somewhere.

Any ideas on how to ensure the image is dynamically fetched every time?

Answer (score 7):

**On the server side:**

Add an adequate Cache-Control header in the server's response for the image. E.g. `Cache-Control: max-age=0` - On Apache this could be achieved through a .htaccess file using the [Header](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html#header) directive. Please add details about the used web server to your question if you need further information on how to configure this.

**On the client side:**

Set [browser.cache.check_doc_frequency](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.cache.check_doc_frequency) to 1 in  *Tools* –> *Options* –> *Advanced* –> *General* -> *Config Editor...*

Either way will work to prevent Thunderbird from using the image without checking the cache freshness, but you probably want to use the server side way to make sure your *recipients* see your signature correctly.

Comment: The client side worked well. I just needed to restart tb

Comment: In Apache you can set in a .htaccess file:
``ExpiresActive On ExpiresByType image/png A1800``
TB will reload the PNG image every 30 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

You can manually purge Thunderbird's image cache by deleting the TB cache directory:

- close TB
- navigate to your TB profile folder...

  - on Windows: 
    `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Thunderbird\Profiles\YOUR_PROFILE_NAME.default`
  - on Mac OS X: 
    `/Users/YOUR_USER_NAME/Library/Caches/Thunderbird/Profiles/YOUR_PROFILE_NAME.default`
  - **Attention:** In both cases those folders are hidden by default!
- delete or rename the sub-folder `Cache` in your profile
- restart TB

Answer (score 1):

Thunderbird now ships with the option to clear the cache.
Go to **Tools -> Clear recent history…**

Comment: I had to restart Thunderbird after clearing the cache (all time cache) to have it fetch the linked image in the HTML mail again.

Answer (score 0):

How about generating a new filename each time, and dynamically updating your sig file as well?  More work than just replacing the image, but less work possibly than changing the server header response.